# Numbering unordered, non-repetitive pair

Tags: math, hash

Recently, I have encountered an interesting question in coding, where I would like to generate all combinations of choosing 2 elements from a collection. For fast indexing, I would like to have a function that maps original chosen indices to the index of that pair in the result. To be accurate, I'm thinking of a function `f: {{i,j}: i,j in 0~(n-1), i!=j} -> 0~(n choose 2 - 1)` that is a bijection. I've looked up unordered pairing function and hash functions, but they either include pairs where `i == j`, or they do not map into my desired range. Therefore, I'm wondering if it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd reorder `(i, j)` so that `j > i`.

Then the index:

```
p = i(2n - i - 3)/2 + j - 1
```

So for example, when n = 5:

```
 i j   p
 - -   -
(0,1)  0
(0,2)  1
(0,3)  2
(0,4)  3
(1,2)  4
(1,3)  5
(1,4)  6
(2,3)  7
(2,4)  8
(3,4)  9
```